# I have got bug on debugging in the android studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-gradle-plugin

I am making a simple app but when I want to debug something In the console `Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'` pop up and then happen nothing I mean nothing show in my debugger.I wait for a long time but nothing happen.When I worked on android studio 0.8(Beta) it works fine but recently I updated my android studio to 1.3.2  got this bug.I am using Genymotion as an emulator.
My mainactivity is

```
package com.example.niyamat.stormyy;

 import android.content.Context;
  import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
  import android.net.NetworkInfo;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
  import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
  import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
  import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
  import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

 import java.io.IOException;

   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    double latitude = 23.7000;
    double longitude = -90.3500;
    String apiKey = "b4de63a98386f7e128deaa126a3e23dd";
    String forecastUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey + "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;


    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(forecastUrl)
            .build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            String jsonData = response.body().string();

            try {
             Log.v(TAG, jsonData);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Exception caught", e);
            }
        }
    });

}


        }
```

**Log.v(TAG, jsonData);** where I set my breakpoint.
My gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.niyamat.stormyy"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
}
```

Please help me.I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
 There is a Debug icon on the toolbar. It looks like a little "bug" and is l   
 located right next to the Run icon (which looks like a play button). Try  
 launching the application with that.

 Edit: The following is deprecated when using Android Studio with Gradle.

 There is also a debug flag in the AndroidManifest.xml file. It is located
 under the application tag, and should be set to "true", as follows:
 <application android:debuggable="true">
 </application>
```

Comment: otherwise u must try this:Go to Tools==>android==>disable adb integration and again enable it

after that unpluged USB from device and again plugged. Finally press shift + F9